# Is datagridview the fastest control for this?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 100 items, from items 1 to items 100. I only want to display 5 items each time and when the user click on the down button once, it will display from item 2 to 6. When I click again, it will display from item 3 to 7.

I was thinking to reset the whole datagridview and redraw it once the arrow is clicked. But I am worried it is too slow. Is there a more suitable control for this application?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 100 item in a DataGrid is ok IMHO.

However, if you want the fastest possible solution, I suggest you to use a ListView with the VirtualMode enabled.